# VB.NET Deleting row from dataTable is removing all rows

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am having one heck of a time deleting one row from a datatable.
I'm using this code:

```
    Dim foundRow As DataRow() = nodes.Select("identifier LIKE '*Scene Root*'")
    If foundRow.Count > 0 Then foundRow(0).Delete()
    nodes.AcceptChanges()
```

The problem is this is removing ALL rows from the datatable.

```
       Dset.Tables("node").Rows(0).Delete()
```

That also deletes all rows from the table. I am a little confused as to why this is happening.
Help me regain my sanity!

I should add.. I have single stepped first example and it finds one row and it IS the row I want to delete but the actual .delete is deleting every row in the table.
Maybe its what's in the table?
[image]

Comment: what is `nodes` and how does it related to `Dset.Tables("node")` ot looks like you are querying one object and acting on another.  I would also not use LIKE.  Your code shows that you have the exact identifier, just use it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but try this : `node.Rows(foundRow(0)).Delete()` ... But, like @Nestor wrote, maybe Your code running repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely your code is running repeatedly. Try putting a `Debug.WriteLine("Hello, world")` in there and see how many times the message appears each time it's supposed to delete one row.

Comment: This is not looping ever.. That one line is deleting all rows.
It was a good idea tho.

Comment: I have restarted Visual Studio and I get the same thing.
I don't know whats going on. It should just delete the one row and it does NOT. It has to be something wrong internally with .NET or the IDE.